# WHY the method with String Parameter gets called and not the method with Object parameter

Tags: java, overloading

```
class Jaguar 
{
void method(Object o)
{
    System.out.println("Object Called");
}
void method(String s)
{
    System.out.println("String Called");
}
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Jaguar j=new Jaguar();
    j.method(null);
}
}
```

Question:The o/p of the code is String Called and not ObjectCalled..Why?? null value is applicable to objects also..

Comment: Object is the highest class available. But if a subclass is available, it will be called. Moreover, everything is firstly convert to String (if available), not to Object. You'll mostly have to cast to Object.

Answer (score 2):

Java will always try to use the most specific applicable version of a method that's available see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5

Object and String can all take null as a valid value. Therefore all 3 version is applicable, so Java will have to find the most specific one.

Since Object is the supertype of String, the String version is more specific than the Object-version. So if only those two methods exist, the String version will be chosen.

Each pair of these three methods is ambiguous by itself when called with a null argument. Because each parameter type is a reference type.

The following are the three ways to call one specific method of yours with null.

```
doSomething( (Object) null);
doSomething( (String) null);
```

> If you add one more method with object subclass example Integer then the compiler will throw **ambiguous method error** as in that case compiler cannot decide if which method can be called string one or integer one.

I hope this helps.